# pip install [all] not installing dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, statsmodels

I am trying to install `statsmodels` and all its dependencies using `pip install statsmodels[all]`.

**Question:** Why is it still telling me that there are missing dependencies?

**Output:**

```
Downloading/unpacking statsmodels[all]
  Using download cache from /Users/mynusername/.pip/cache/https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fs%2Fstatsmodels%2Fstatsmodels-0.5.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package statsmodels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/Users/mynusername/.virtualenvs/datasci/build/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>
        check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
      File "/Users/mynusername/.virtualenvs/datasci/build/statsmodels/setup.py", line 122, in check_dependency_versions
        raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")
    ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/Users/mynusername/.virtualenvs/datasci/build/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>

    check_dependency_versions(min_versions)

  File "/Users/mynusername/.virtualenvs/datasci/build/statsmodels/setup.py", line 122, in check_dependency_versions

    raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")

ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we chose not to necessitate that the packaging tools install the dependencies for you.

Comment: Because I "hate" it when pip uninstalls my numpy by trying to update it when I want to install or update a package that **requires** numpy. pip doesn't actually manage to install numpy on Windows since it doesn't use binaries.